# Is there a way to clear your wand of spells you've used?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I know you can see the last spell someone cast (from memory, this was in the Goblet of Fire), but is there a spell that can, for lack of a better phrase, clear your wands' history?

Comment: I assume you're worried that your parents/significant other will look at your wand history and find something icky.

Comment: Just cast another spell.. or a few of them in case there is some depth to the "memory".

Comment: *"Why have you been casting Engorgio! over and over again, honey?"*

Comment: I think the only sure fire way to erase your wand's history is to completely destroy your wand. But this seems to be a bit excessive just to hide @Valorum's repeated use of Engorgio...

Comment: *Dehistorio*? *Controlis Altdel*?

Comment: Remember young wizards and witches, always use the Chromium Incognitum modus spell!

Answer (score 6):

There are no "Clear browser" spells shown in the Potter books, films or other literature. You do have some other options though, if you're worried about something finding out [what you've been up to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGrvQ1c5khU).

[image]

---

### Security by buffer overflow.

We know from Goblet of Fire that it's possible to get a wand to regurgitate the wand's spells in reverse chronological order. What we don't see is the wand continue to regurgitate spells *past a certain point*.

By casting innoccuous spells (such as 'lumos') several dozen times, you may push the spell/s you wish to hide beyond the wand's ability to "remember" them. This obviously assumes that the wand doesn't just regurgitate *all* of them regardless of age.

### Security by labour-intensivity

The spells seem to "erupt" from the wand at a rate of around one every 10-20 seconds, far slower than you can cast them. By casting thousands of quick spells over the course of several days, you could hide the spell you want to hide in a mass of other spells or simply make the process too labour-intensive for your opponent to bother with. After they've sat through a few hours of lumos, lumos, lumos, lumos, lumos they've probably given up, assuming you've found a way to stop the spell from working correctly.

### Security through lack of interest

Priori Incantato seems a pretty rare and powerful spell and Priori Incantatem doubly so. If you avoid doing anything *exciting* with your life, it's unlikely you'll ever be put into a position where one of these rare powerful witches or wizards takes sufficient interest in you to actually cast this spell.

### Security by "snap"

Broken wands can't be repaired except through the application of the most powerful magic. Snapping your wand in half would seem an excellent way of preventing the memory from being read, especially if you have a small supply of spare wands lying around.

Comment: If there are spells that throw fireballs, would it be dangerous to have  the wand regurgitate them?  If forget if this process recasts the spells or just reveals the spells cast.

Comment: @user3294068 - It doesn't regurgitate the spell, just an "echo" of it. Apparently with sufficient finesse you can even work out what they were cast on and why.

Comment: Broken wands are shown to be able to work, albeit unreliably.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica - Not fully snapped, I don't think

Answer (score -1):

Priori Incantato seems to regurgitate spells in reverse order they were cast. If you use it twice then the most recent and second most recent spell shows up, but as far as I know there's no way to go back to check those two spells. Therefore, if you use it on your wand right after you cast a spell you wish to hide there's no way to find out it was you who cast the Dark Mark.

Comment: Can you offer an example of this happening?

Comment: Lord Voldemort's spell kept echoing in reverse order they were cast at the graveyard.